# How to enable jslint plugin in Notepad++ to recognize es6 features like "=>"

Tags: javascript, node.js, notepad++, ecmascript-6, jslint

Is it possible to enable ES6 features in the jslint plugin for Notepad++?

I tried setting the option es6 and ES6 to true but that doesn't seem to work.

Specifically I'm using the arrow functions "=>" and getting jslint errors saying expected an identifier and saw ">".

This is for programs running under node.js v 4.2.1 using notepad++ as the editor in a Windows 2012 R2 environment.

Comment: Can you replace a jslint.js file anywhere in Notepad++?

Comment: I couldn't find one to replace.  The plugin is in a JSLintNpp.dll library file downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/

Comment: I don't really think JSLint supports es6. You'll need to use something like [ESLint](http://eslint.org/).

Comment: @Asad Saeeduddin According to https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.html  it does: "  <div><label><input title=es6 type=checkbox>ES6</label></div>"   Either I don't know how to enable it in notepad++ or it hasn't been implemted there.  Wonderring if anyone else has been able to use jslint in notepad++ for es6.  Also here: http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin In the latest version (check jslint.com) it does. Been out a couple of months. Will have to check notepad++ next time I'm in front of a Windows box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.  Add

```
/*jslint es6:true*/
```

at the beginning of the program and get the latest jslint plugin for notepad++ at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/

Comment: This did **not** work for me even after grabbing the latest version of jslint from source forge (JSLintNPP.0.8.3)

Comment: @TxRegex Works fine for me on Win 10 and use it every day.

Comment: Type it like this. 
`<!--/*jslint es6:true*/ -->`

Answer (score 2):

Add at the beginning of your code:

```
/*jslint esnext:true*/
```

Comment: Please consider providing an explanation : [How do I write a good answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Mickael esnext does not work.  It generates messages like "Unexpected es6 feature".  I accepted the correct answer as being jslint es6:true.

Comment: It works for me. And it's future proof, while es6 is specific to version 6. I put "esnext: true" (no quotes) into the Additional options box in the JSLint options.